# Javascript progress bar clear value after load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, progress-bar, jprogressbar

I have a simple HTML page with a JavaScript progress bar.
My page reload every 30 seconds and my progress bar is set to 30 seconds of loading.

What I want is to clear the value of progress bar every time the page reload and start to load again from 0 to 100%. Can anyone help me with this? Thank you!

Here's what I have so far.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="val1" placeholder="Search" onKeyPress="Val1KeyPress()" onKeyUp="Val1KeyPress()"/>

<input type = "text" id="date" placeholder="date to">
            <img src="cal1.png" />
            <input type = "text" id="date1" placeholder="date from">
            <img src="cal2.png" />
            <input type="submit" id="btn_search"  value="search"/>


<div class = "iframe-div">
            <iframe id="iframe" src='http://mypage.aspx' runat="server" allowTransparency='true' width='850px' height='500px'>
            </iframe> 

        </div>

  <div id="progressbar" class="progress-wrap progress" data-progress-percent="100">
  <div class="progress-bar progress"></div>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
  .progress {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top:-10px !important;
}

.progress-wrap {
  background: #f80;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.progress-wrap .progress-bar {
  background: #ddd;
  position: absolute;

}
```

**Javascript**

```
    <script>
function setURL(url){
    document.getElementById('iframe').src = url;
}
</script>

<script>
    function Val1KeyPress()
    {
        var val1 = document.getElementById("val1");
        var sr = val1.value;
        var lblValue = document.getElementById("lblValue");
        lblValue.innerText = " "+s;
    }
    function sample(){
        var val1 = document.getElementById("val1");
        var sr = val1.value;

        var date = document.getElementById("date");
        var dtep = "&dateto=".concat(date.value);

        var date1 = document.getElementById("date1");
        var dtep1 = "&datefrm=".concat(date1.value);

        setURL('http://mypage.aspx?search='.concat(sr, dtep, dtep1))
    }
</script>


  <script>
    var picker = new pikdate
    (
{
    field: document.getElementById('date'),
    firstDay: 1,
    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
    minDate: new Date(2000, 0, 1),
    maxDate: new Date(2020, 12, 31),
    yearRange: [2000, 2020]
});
</script>
 <script>
     var picker = new Pikaday(
{
    field: document.getElementById('date1'),
    firstDay: 1,
    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
    minDate: new Date(2000, 0, 1),
    maxDate: new Date(2020, 12, 31),
    yearRange: [2000, 2020]
});

</script>

  <script>


 moveProgressBar();
    $(window).resize(function() {
        moveProgressBar();
    });
    function moveProgressBar() {
      console.log("moveProgressBar");
        var getPercent = ($('.progress-wrap').data('progress-percent') / 100);
        var getProgressWrapWidth = $('.progress-wrap').width();
        var progressTotal = getPercent * getProgressWrapWidth;
        var animationLength = 30000;

        // on page load, animate percentage bar to data percentage length
        // .stop() used to prevent animation queueing
        $('.progress-bar').stop().animate({
            left: progressTotal
        }, animationLength);
            clearInterval('.progress-wrap');

         var interval = setInterval(function () {
            clearInterval(interval);

               setURL('http://mypage.aspx?search?stat=');})
            setTimeout(arguments.callee, 31000);
}
```

Comment: Your entire page reload after 30 seconds? Then you don't JS to make a progress bar which completes in 30 seconds. You can just use CSS animation. If some part of you page changes after 30 and you need to restart the progress bar then you'll need a some JS. What one are you trying to do?

Comment: @NamanNehra Hi, I'm trying to accomplish the progress bar to restart from loading every after the entire page reload.

Comment: Where is the setURL function defined?

Comment: @NamanNehra I have edited the code above. Sorry I forgot to indicate the setURL part. Thank you.

Comment: So you want to restart the progress-bar which is on the parent frame and reload an iframe and it's complete?

Comment: I have again updated the answer. Try it.

Comment: OH MY GAAAD! It works!!! Thank you so much! You saved me! Thank youuuuuu!!!!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style>
    @keyframes progress {
        from {
            transform: scale(0, 1);
        }
        to {
            transform: none;
        }
    }
    .progress {
        background-color: blue; /*some color*/
        height: 4px; /*some height*/
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        transform-origin: left;
    }
    .animation {
        animation: progress 30s;
    }
</style>
<div class="progress animation"></div>
<script>
    var progressBar = document.querySelector('.progress');
    function restartprogressBar() {
        progressBar.classList.remove('animation');
        progressBar.offsetWidth = progressBar.offsetWidth;
        progressBar.classList.add('animation');
    };
    setInterval(function() {
        //setURL function comes here
        restartprogressBar();
    }, 30000);
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/namannehra/osae4u5e/

Comment: Thank you @Naman Nehra . But can you please help me to your script with page reloading. I don't how I might accomplish your pure css with javascript reloading after the progressbar loaded.

Comment: You don't need to write anything extra for page reloading. It'll just run again when page reloads. Or you need the code to reload the page after 30 seconds?

Comment: Yup, exactly. I need a code to reload the page after 30 seconds. Can you please help me? Thank you.

Comment: I need the code that refresh the page after "every" 30seconds and also the code for the progressbar to restart from loading after every 30seconds also.

Comment: I have updated the answer. I have added the code to refresh the page. What I am trying to explain to you is that you don't to write extra code for progressbar on relaod as the code which ran the first time will run again on refresh.

Comment: Hi your code is pretty cool but when I did the code below the progressbar is not running.                                                                   <script>
    setTimeout(function() {
    // location.reload();
    
    // location.reload();
    setURL('http://mypage/mypage.aspx?stat=-refresh');
}, 30000)

 </script>

Comment: Why are you using setURL? The code which I wrote is working in my browser. https://jsfiddle.net/wrmo66gn/1/ If this doesn't in your browser then you are probably using an older browser. Or have you made changes to code before running? In that case post your code and I'll look for the problem.

Comment: Hi, I'm using setURL because I have the JavaScript function for reloading of my page. Please see the code above. And yes your code is working, but when I make it setURL('http://samplepage/widget/my.aspx?stat=');}) instead of location reload the progress bar stock and never run again.

Comment: location.reload is for reloading the page. You don't need setURL.

Comment: location.reload is not working on my page. Because I am using iframe. setURL is perfectly working but the progressbar won't work. =( I'm stock. I need a help, really. :( Thank you.

Comment: call location.reload after setURL. If that doesn't work then post the code where you have defined setURL function.

Comment: use top.location.reload(); to if you want to reload parent frame from an iframe

Comment: The page is reloading but the update is not. I'll edit my code above showing my complete JS function where I defined my setURL. Thank you.

Comment: I have updated my codes above. I posted my complete code. Thank you.

Comment: That is codes where the page is reloading every after 30 seconds everthings working great except the progress bar that is not resetting or not reloading again, but the page is still reloading/refreshing after every 30 seconds.